# Rounding double to specific number of decimal places -- Math.Round vs Convert.ToDouble(ToString())

Tags: c#, rounding

A proposed fix for a rounding (for reporting) problem is

```
private double RoundedResult(double v, int digits) 
{
    // return Math.Round(value, digits); 
    // sometimes does not do proper rounding per user feedback

    // proposed fix relies on a fixed decimal (F) format rendering converted back to double
    return
      Convert.ToDouble
      (
          v.ToString("F"+digits);
      );
}
```

I am uncertain as to the vagaries of the F*n* format.

Question: Is the above a reasonable fix? , and can it cause other problems later ?

**Background**

An individual report will have < 1,000 rounded numbers in it, so I am not worried about performance.

I am working with legacy system using SQL Server and ASP NET MVC application code.  Data values are `double?` and values need to be rounded to a varying number of decimals for reporting.  I know the system should be using decimal data values instead of double, but I am stuck with the legacy double.

The end-user has complained about this particular situation (and other similar):

> *The text data file has 0.000065, the data base viewer shows 0.000065 and the reporting (to 5 decimal places) shows 0.00006 instead of 0.00007.  Reporting should always round up.*

The text file information is

I am working through the specifics of

```
double? value = 0.000065;
```

I am aware that `0.000065d` must actually be ever so slightly less than `0.000065m`:

- `Math.Round(value.Value,5,...)` returns `0.00006`, using both `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` and `ToEven`.
- Debugger shows `0.000065d-0.000065f` as `-1.7695129487117073E-13 double`
- Single cast of the value rounds up, the debugger watch shows

  - `Math.Round((Single)value,5)    7E-05   double`

Slightly perplexing

- `value.Value.ToString("F5")` returns `"0.00007"`

I don't know if `F5` does any sort of internal casting, but the result corresponds with rounding the single cast.  `ToString()` (aka `String.Format()`) has some sort of mojo going on.

The single case of rounding the single cast of the double 0.000065 'worked' by yielding 0.0007, but probably won't in all cases.

**Fiddle code**

I wrote a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WPJHmR) to iterate over a large number of 'ending in 5' cases, and it seems that ToString("F5") always yielded the 'human-expected' result.

Comment: This seems more like a question for Code Review site...

Comment: Never used code review site before, is there a question migration tool or policy about cross posting ?